# NodeJS decryption of bitnami sealed secrets

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, encryption, bitnami, sealedsecret

I want to reverse this encryption procedure in order to decrypt a sealed secret.
this is taken from the **bitnami** documentation.

#### Secret encryption

The secret is encrypted by AES-256-GCM with a randomly-generated single-use 32 byte session key.

The result of this operation will be called `AES encrypted data` in the next diagram, and the present step is the `1.`.

#### Session key encryption

The session key used by AES-256-GCM to encrypt the Secret is encapsulated with the controller's public key using RSA-OAEP with SHA256.

The OAEP input content, called `label` in the next diagram, differs depending on the sealed secret controller scope configuration. This algorithm is only used to encrypt the AES session key.

- Default scope configuration : `label` is equal to the concatenation of the Secret's namespace and the Secret's name.
- Namespace-wide scope configuration : `label` is equal to the Secret's namespace.
- Cluster-wide scope configuration : `label` is empty.

The result of the RSA-OAEP encryption is called `RSA encrypted data` in the next diagram, and the present step is the `2.`.

#### Sealed Secret storage

The final Sealed Secret data format is the following (where `||` is the concatenation operator): `size of AES encrypted key (2 bytes) || RSA encrypted data || AES encrypted data`

#### Diagram to summarize

```
                                Secret
                                                                   |
                                                                   │
                                                   K_s────────────►│
                                                    │              │
                                       K_pub───────►│              │
                                                    │              │ 1.
                                       label───────►│ 2.           │
                                                    │              │
                     ┌──────────────────────┬───────▼───────┬──────▼───────┐
Sealed Secret data = │size of AES encrypted │ RSA encrypted │ AES encrypted│
                     │key (2 bytes)         │ data          │ data         │
                     └──────────────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┘

K_s = 256 bits single-use session key, used by AES-GCM
K_pub = Public key from the self-signed certificate, used by RSA-OAEP
label = Additional input for RSA-OAEP encryption.
        Content differs depending on the scope configuration:
         * Default config : label = Secret's namespace || Secret's name
         * Namespace-wide : label = Secret's namespace
         * Cluster-wide : label is empty
```

#### Decryption process

The decryption is simply the inversion of the encryption.

`Size of AES encrypted key` is read and used to separate `RSA encrypted data` and `AES encrypted data` properly.

Then the private key associated with the public key (see Session key encryption) is used with the `label` to decrypt the `RSA encrypted data`, effectively retrieving the AES session key.

To end this process, the `AES encrypted data` is decrypted using the AES session key, therefore unsealing the original Secret.

**this is what i have done till now, but i am stuck:**

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as forge from 'node-forge';

// Load the private key from my local files
const privateKeyPEM = fs.readFileSync('priv.key', 'utf8');
const privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(privateKeyPEM);

// Sealed Secret data
const sealedSecretData = Buffer.from(
  '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',
  'base64'
);

// Parse the Sealed Secret data
const aesKeySize = sealedSecretData.readUIntBE(0,2);
const rsaEncryptedData = sealedSecretData.slice(2, 2 + aesKeySize);
const aesEncryptedData = sealedSecretData.slice(2 + aesKeySize , sealedSecretData.length - 1);

// the label as specified in the docs above
const label = Buffer.from('kube-systemsealed-secrets-keyfc5ht', 'utf8'); 

// Decrypt RSA encrypted data to get the AES session key
const rsaEncryptedBuffer = forge.util.createBuffer(rsaEncryptedData.toString('binary'));
const rsaDecryptedBytes = privateKey.decrypt(rsaEncryptedBuffer.getBytes(), 'RSA-OAEP', {
  md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
  label,
});

const aesSessionKey = forge.util.createBuffer(rsaDecryptedBytes).getBytes();

// Decrypt AES encrypted data
const aesDecipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-GCM', forge.util.hexToBytes(aesSessionKey));
aesDecipher.start({ iv: aesEncryptedData.slice(0, 16) });
aesDecipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(aesEncryptedData.slice(16)));
aesDecipher.finish();

const decryptedSecretData = aesDecipher.output.getBytes();

console.log(decryptedSecretData);
```

i get an error as follows:
**Error: Invalid RSAES-OAEP padding.**

Comment: Link to the docs you're citing (by using normal link [markdown](/markdown) for "bitnami documentation") and don't use all this bold and heading markdown. Your post isn't a dissertation, it doesn't need it. Just [explain your problem](/help/how-to-ask) in terms of (1) what you set out to achieve, (2) the information you found to have that effort, (3) the code you wrote to do that, (4) the result of running that code and a description of how that wasn't what you expected, and _all-important_: (5) a description of what you already did in terms of debugging and (re)searching that problem.

Comment: Presumably the text 'here goes the sealed secret' should be a base64 string that you've chosen not to disclose, so it's a little hard to say but `const rsaEncryptedData = sealedSecretData.slice(2, 2 + aesKeySize);` doesn't look right. RSA Encrypted Data should not be the size of an AES key (i.e. 128, 192 or 256 bits), it's typically larger. More like 2048 bits for example possibly plus padding and other format information. Could it be that you should be swapping `rsaEncryptedData` and `aesEncryptedData` in the two assignment statements?

Comment: @Xecrets thank you for the notice, i did change it but the question that remains how to give in the label while decrypting with node-forge.
and the sealed secret i am trying to decrypt looks like , i have updated the code above this in case that helps.

Comment: Ok, it's a little hard to test without the private key. Reading the documentation, I realize it's a bit confusing. The first 2 bytes "Size of AES encrypted key", really should read "Size of RSA encrypted data" (which is the "AES key encrypted with RSA"). But the code now seems ok there although later you'll need to change `const aesEncryptedData =...(..., sealedSecretData.length - 1);` to `const aesEncryptedData =...(..., sealedSecretData.length);` Try using Buffer directly: `const rsaDecryptedBytes = privateKey.decrypt(rsaEncryptedData, 'RSA-OAEP',...`. Are you sure the label is correct?

Comment: If you can provide the private key, assuming it's not a real production key but just a test key, it will make it easier to fully test your code. If it's a real key, don't!

Comment: yeah i am sure of the label. after much time spent we decided to go another route and just execute the kubeseal commands with the help of shellJS, since the entire process is not clear at all from the docs alone. Thank you so much for your effort @Xecrets